# Multiple rgba borders cancels the others

Tags: css

If I apply multiple borders to a div, with a rgba color with an alpha lower than 1 neither border is applied. It does however work with just one border, or with 'solid' colors.

```css
div {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  background: lightgray;
}

#one {
  border-top: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, .3);
  border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, .3);
}

#two {
  border-top: 1px solid black;
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}

#three {
  border-top: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
  border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
}
```

```html
<div id="one"></div>
<br>
<div id="two"></div>
<br>
<div id="three"></div>
```

Comment: Which browser are you using? I see the borders just fine on all the `div`s...

Comment: works as expected in Firefox, Chrome and Safari on MacOS...

Comment: thanks, issue was related to some hidden chrome settings, a complete settings clear fixed the issue.